# Обработка each после добавления javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток есть код 
html

```
<form>
    <label id="childName" class="plus">
        <span>введите данные на  ребенка</span>
        <input type="text" name="childName[]" class="childName" value=""/>
        <a href="#">+</a>
    </label>
    <a href="#" class="submit" id="add">Внести</a>
</form>
```

js

```
jQuery('form').on('click', '#childName a', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var plus = "<span>введите данные ещё одного ребенка</span> <input type='text' name='childName[]' class='child'/><a href='#'>+</a>";
    $('#childName').append(plus);
});
```

надо что бы после клика на

```
<a href="#" class="submit" id="add">Внести</a>
```

вываливался alert  со всеми value инпутов пишу так

```
$("#add").click(function(e){
     var cN="";
    $('form .childName').each(function(){
        cN +=$(this).val()+" ";
        alert('cN');
    });
}
```

получаю это Иванова Ирина Ивановна;

```
$('form').on('each', '.childName',function(){
    cN +=$('form .childName').val()+" ";
    alert(cN);
});
```

вообще ни чего не получаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вызываете `alert` *для каждого элемента* `input`. Нужно так:

```
$("#add").click(function(e){
    var cN = '';
    $('form .childName').each(function(){
        cN += $(this).val() + ' ';
    });

    alert(cN);
}
```

**UPD:**

А еще у вас там есть очепятка. Вместо:

```
var plus = "<span>введите данные ещё одного ребенка</span> <input type='text' name='childName[]' class='child'/><a href='#'>+</a>";
```

должно быть:

```
var plus = "<span>введите данные ещё одного ребенка</span> <input type='text' name='childName[]' class='childName'/><a href='#'>+</a>";
```

Обратите внимание на названия класса, должно быть `childName`, а не `child`!

А вот и работающий JSFiddle с исправленным кодом: http://jsfiddle.net/tg2x6c3g/

Comment: Объявлена на самом деле просто не присвоено =" "; хорошо от undefined освободились (это было не так важно) мне надо получить все value всех созданых js инпутов

Comment: за очепятку спасибо не заметил это и вызывало ошибку.